# Are there any test image library for camera calibration simulation experiment?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I want to verify an algorithm about camera calibration. But using the pictures taken by myself is not convincing. Are there any canonical image libraries for camera calibration simulation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by calibration, but take a look at MNIST.

Comment: MNIST is too small for camera calibration in 98% of the cases. I guess a good question here is what type of camera parameters do you want to calibrate?

Comment: @arrowd: MNIST has absolutely nothing to do with camera calibration. Please avoid such random suggestions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't leave an answer, it is a comment.

Comment: @arrowd: ok, rephrased.

Comment: ok, MNIST seems no relationship to my question. But thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the page [*A Flexible New Technique for Camera Calibration*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/a-flexible-new-technique-for-camera-calibration-2/) by Zhengyou Zhang; in the section "Experimental data and result for camera calibration", you will find five images like this one [image], five sets of image coordinates (like for example this one https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/imagepointsone.txt) and the result of the calibration here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/completecalibration.txt

I do not know whether it is canonical or not, for sure Zhengyou Zhang is well known for his work related to camera calibration and his article:

ZHANG, Zhengyou. A flexible new technique for camera calibration. *IEEE Transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence*, 2000, 22.11: 1330-1334.

is highly cited.

You may also have a look at [*Camera Calibration Toolbox for Matlab*](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) by  Jean-Yves Bouguet, his code is the basis for the OpenCV algorithms but I do not know whether there are images for accuracy and correctness testing.

Comment: Yes, Zhang's method is very famous, I have read it before. It may not have some canonical test library online, but thank you all the same.

Comment: (^V^), these five sets seem useful. But the result confused me. What are the meaning of  1st and 2nd row. Are the other five matrix extrinsic matrix?